# magento 2 payment methods page keep reloading

Tags: magento2

I am a beginner to magento2 and installed magento CE 2.0.0 version . Whenever i access configuration  payment methods that page keep reloading and antivirus blocks URL.is it virus issue ?can anybody help to solve this issue.